# Rails - Delegate method to last record in has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with A with a has_many B model association.
I would like to do something like this in my A model:

```
def my_method
 self.bs.last.my_method
end
```

In other words, I would like to delegate `my_method` to my last B object in the association. Is that possible to achieve with delegate? Think it would be more elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do that if you create a method to return the last 'bs' object:

```
def last_bs
  self.bs.last
end
```

then delegate:

```
delegate :my_method, to: :last_bs
```

UPDATE: This can also be achieved by:

```
delegate :my_method, to: "bs.last", allow_nil: true
```

Comment: Thanks, bro! This worked, but if you could update your answer, I got it how to do that directly on delegate, like: delegate :my_method, to: "bs.last", allow_nil: true